# perl twitter search only return latest tweet

Tags: perl, search, twitter

With this PERL code snippet, which works fine but has started only ever returns the latest tweet from Twitter? Have a got this correct, it should return an array of tweets?

```
$nt = Net::Twitter::Lite::WithAPIv1_1->new(%consumer_tokens);
$r = $nt->search({q=>'@hullpsy'});

foreach $status ( @{$r->{statuses}} )
{
    $stweet = $status->{text};
    $ssender = $status->{user}{screen_name};
    $screby = $status->{created_at};
    $stweet =~ s/  / /gi;
    $stweet =~ s/\n/ /gi;
    $stweet =~ s/\://g;
    print "$screby:$ssender:$stweet\n";
}
```

Comment: Don't know what api call that library makes but I'm experiencing the same problem calling $get_tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" . $twitter_user_id . "&count=" . $tweets_to_display . "&include_rts=" . $include_rts . "&exclude_replies=" . $exclude_replies);
 where only one result is returned.

Answer (score 1):

The [module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Twitter-Lite/lib/Net/Twitter/Lite.pod#Search-API-Methods) suggest that you should be iterating over `@{$r->results}`, 
not `@{$r->statuses}`